# How would one design a circuit to swtich between external power source and a battery?

Tags: power-supply, power, batteries

I have a circuit that normally runs off of a 12V power brick that I want to make somewhat mobile. As such, I plan to use a 12V battery to power the circuit but, when the battery depletes, I would like the ability to plug the circuit to a 12V DC power supply that would not only charge the battery but would also supply the circuit with power.

The circuit that I want to power is actually a 4 meter long LED strip that I used to make a lighting panel. I intend to make this panel more mobile for whenever I need it to be so I can easily move it around without worrying about the cable. However, in case the battery runs out, I still want to be able to run the panel from a wall plug and, in the mean time, also charge up the battery.

To sum it up, these are the 2 use cases for what I am after:

1. If the external power supply is unplugged, the lighting panel will run solely off of the battery.
2. If the external power supply is plugged, the lighting panel will run (ideally) solely off of the external power supply which would also charge up the battery in parallel.
3. When I don't need the panel to be mobile I would like to keep it plugged in so the battery won't discharge but still use the external supply to power the strip.

Currently, I have not looked into any specific type of battery / charger. This is all still in the design phase and I first want to have a plan set up before I think of the specifications of the parts I will be using. For now, the only specific characteristic will be the 12V for the supply and battery and also the LED strip. I am not sure how much current the 12V supply will need to provide or how much the charger and the strip will draw when running simultaneously. Once I have an appropriate circuit, I will look for the parts that suit my needs. I should mention that I will want a battery and charger combo.

Here is the first circuit that I came up with:
[image]

I tried to keep it simple and not use any transistor, just a couple of diodes.

First off, the charger will have 4 terminals and is represented by the 4 pin header. The inner 2 pins represent the power in for the charger and the outer 2 pins represent the terminals of the charger that connect to the terminals of the battery.

The D3 diode prevents the current flow from the external supply to the battery, and the second diode, D2, is used when disconnecting the power supply from the circuit to prevent any current flow from the battery to the charger. I don't think it is really necessary, especially if the charger is any good, but it's there just for good measure.

My concerns are regarding the common ground that the battery, charger and external supply share as I'm not entirely sure how it would all work, and also I'm unsure if the circuit will draw current from the battery once the external supply is connected. While it is charging, the battery will probably provide a lower voltage than the external supply so the strip will probably draw its current from the external supply but what about when the battery is fully charged? Will the strip also draw current from the battery? How will that affect the charger / battery?

I am not yet sure as to what battery I will be using but I will probably go with a LiPo battery pack and the appropriate charger (I will probably buy a combo from the same manufacturer). In the case of a LiPo there may be a third terminal between the battery and the charger.

What are your suggestions regarding my design or perhaps there is a better alternative that I have not thought of that you might be able to suggest?

Are there any safe practices that I have overlooked or is there any standard circuit that would accomplish what it is I am trying to achieve?

EDIT: I would also like to get at least 2 hours of full brightness use out of the LEDs.

Comment: The current you need, and for how long, will influence your choice of battery chemistry. This in turn will influence the charging circuit. You can't design this without all the requirements up front.

Comment: Whichever battery and charging circuit I choose, think of the battery and charger as a single unit with 4 terminals. 2 for the supply of the charger and 2 for the output of the battery. In any case, that is why I stated I will most likely use a LiPo battery. Am I wrong in my simplification of the problem?

Comment: Well for a start, you have a diode drop between your charger and battery. Some batteries, e.g. LiPo require a charging period split between constant current and constant voltage, and need good control for safe charging. Do you have any good reason to keep your current/power requirements secret? Oh, and do you have a 12V LiPo?

Comment: In all honesty, I have not yet calculated the exact current my light strip draws. It works off of 12V and... as a rough calculation it draws around 1.8 amps. For good measure let's assume it draws 2.5 amps. Regarding the battery and charger, I don't want to mess with it more than I have to. In short, the battery / charger will have all the necessary charging and discharge cutoff and temp protection etc circuitry incorporated and I don't want to play with those. As a unit, it should consist of power in to charge it up and power out to power the strip.

Comment: And also, I don't have any battery yet. I want to feel confident that I am up for it before I actually go ahead and acquire my materials. I also don't want to hastily buy something only to later realize it was not appropriate for the task it needs to perform.